# How to create an URL based on array with 30 values

Tags: php, curl, get

I want to pass some variables and a array (with 30 index) into URL using Curl.

To get on another site all variables and array.

```
$an_array=array('c1_key'=>c1_value,'c2_key'=>c3_value,...........'c30_key'=>c30_value);
'http://domain.com?a=1&b=2&c=an_array'
```

Can Anybody tell me how to do this.

Update:

I used `http_build_query()` as @hek2mgl suggested but there are only 14 variables in the resulting url while I passed a 30 index array. Can anybody explain why?

Comment: Please show the output of `var_dump($an_array);` ***and*** provide a working PHP example with your array and the call to `http_build_query`.

Comment: Please add your current code

Answer (score 0):

Use [`http_build_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php). The function is able to work with scalars, numeric arrays and even accociative arrays (in any dimension):

```
$query = array(
    'user' => 'hek2mgl',
    'actions' => array('foo', 'bar'),
    'description' => array(
        'hobby' => 'hacking',
        'likesPHP' => 'yes and no'
    )
);
$url = 'http://www.yourserver.com/script.php?';
$url .= http_build_query($query);
echo $url;
```

Output:

```
http://www.yourserver.com/script.php?user=hek2mgl&actions%5B0%5D=foo&actions%5B1%5D=bar&description%5Bhobby%5D=hacking&description%5BlikesPHP%5D=yes+and+no
```

Comment: I used it.It's work. But it send only 14 variables in url Why.? I have   array of 20 indexes

Comment: update your question and add your code. Will need it to say more

Answer (score 0):

You can use serialize($array); which will give you string formatted array content send it with url_encode() on that string and then append it  on url as you are doing it. which on server side you can unserialize(url_decode ($_GET ['c'])); and get your array back.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

$_GET is limited.  I suggest using $_POST instead.  You could also take advantage of json_encode() and json_decode();

```
<?php
    // site1
$test = json_encode(array("hello" => "world"));

// site2        
extract(json_decode($test, true));  

echo $hello;
?>
```